# Python3 gives me KeyError when using a tuple as a dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

the problem is that it's difficult to use the inputs as a key for the dictionary in a for loop , I tried to use tuple and list , but the same result

here's the code :

```
import re
morse = {
"A" : ".-", 
"B" : "-...", 
"C" : "-.-.", 
"D" : "-..", 
"E" : ".", 
"F" : "..-.", 
"G" : "--.", 
"H" : "....", 
"I" : "..", 
"J" : ".---", 
"K" : "-.-", 
"L" : ".-..", 
"M" : "--", 
"N" : "-.", 
"O" : "---", 
"P" : ".--.", 
"Q" : "--.-", 
"R" : ".-.", 
"S" : "...", 
"T" : "-", 
"U" : "..-", 
"V" : "...-", 
"W" : ".--", 
"X" : "-..-", 
"Y" : "-.--", 
"Z" : "--..", 
"0" : "-----", 
"1" : ".----", 
"2" : "..---", 
"3" : "...--", 
"4" : "....-", 
"5" : ".....", 
"6" : "-....", 
"7" : "--...", 
"8" : "---..", 
"9" : "----.", 
"." : ".-.-.-", 
"," : "--..--",
" " : " "
}
print("""
                        MORSECODE ENCYPTER """)
print("Enter the text to convert(keep in mind that upper case character, numbers , (.) and (,) are only allowed) :",end = '')
to_encrypt = input()
tuple1 =  tuple( re.findall("." , to_encrypt) )
print (tuple1)  
for i in tuple1 :
    print(morse[tuple1])
```

when I enter the to_encrypt input (for examle H) it gives me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "x.py", line 50, in <module>
print(morse[tuple1])    
KeyError: ('H',)
```

Comment: Why are you using `re` for this? You are using the whole `tuple1`, `morse[i]` should work. But a simple dictionary lookup would do it, `for i in to_encrypt: print(morse[i])`

Comment: I think you want: `for i in tuple1:  print(morse[i])`. Why loop an iterable if you are going to pass the entire iterable to the `dict` (which won't work anyway, since your keys are single characters)?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the to_encode thing , I tried to make it  but it gave me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(morse[to_encrypt]) 
KeyError: 'HH'

Comment: You are passing the whole value in to the dict lookup - use the variable that is iterating over the iterable - namely `i` - `morse[i]`!

Comment: Thanks AChampion that's was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily your for loop seems to be incorrect, you could probably try this out:

```
to_encrypt = list(str(input()))

for ch in to_encrypt:
    morse_val = morse.get(ch, None)

    if not morse_val:
        print('could not encode ', ch)

    else:
        print(morse_val)
```

Let me know if you need better clarification.
P.S - Code above assumes you have defined the `morse` dictionary. Also, I did not see the purpose of using regex in this.

Comment: that's more simple and neat than mine , thank in advance :), I used the regex because I didn't know about the get above , so I made a tuple consisting of every character the user entered to replce it with the dict.